# How to call outside of onClick class

Tags: android

Can someone please tell me how to do this? here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    public s fg = new s();
    public static class Others extends PreferenceFragment{

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_other);

             Preference pref = findPreference("start");
             pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    HOW CAN I CALL S CLASS HERE
                    return false;
                }

             });
        }
    }

}
```

My question is how do I call fg.start() from the Others class. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Others` is `static`, it does not hold a reference to `MainActivity` and thus cannot access its members.

Since `Others` is a `Fragment`, you should not make it non-`static` since fragments holding references to their parent activities is a common source of leaks in Android apps.

To properly answer the question, we would need to know what `s` is. Here are some possibilities for solving the issue:

- If `s` is only needed in the fratment, make `s` a member of the `Others` fragment and create it there.
- If the fragment is only used in `MainActivity`, you can do something like this:

  ```
  ((MainActivity)getActivity()).fg.start();
  ```

  (This creates a fragment-to-hosting-activity dependency which can cause problems later on.)
- If `s` is needed all over your application all the time, you can subclass `Application` and make it a member of it. You can access the application from fragment with `getActivity().getApplication()`.

Comment: s is a class within a different package. As is required everywhere in the app. Thank you for your time mate.